# Problem with namespace installing rJava

Tags: r, package

I am installing rJava on a 64bit machine, running Windows XP, and am encountering the weirdest message. Below is the log. Has anyone seen this before? Thanks in advance.

```
 > install.packages("rJava")
    --- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
    trying URL 'http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/bin/windows/contrib/2.12/rJava_0.8-8.zip'
    Content type 'application/zip' length 636680 bytes (621 Kb)
    opened URL
    downloaded 621 Kb


The downloaded packages are in
        C:\Documents and Settings\wdeng\Local Settings\Temp\RtmpYb4lzb\downloaded_packages
> library("rJava")
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...)
  error: unable to load shared object 'C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-212~1.0/library/rJava/libs/x64/rJava.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  The specified module could not be found.


Error: package/namespace load failed for 'rJava'
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a garden-variety binary incompatibility to me.

The NAMESPACE is a red herring as it happens to load the dynamic library, and that's where the trouble lies.

Answer (score 0):

Does the DLL file exist at that path? If it does, than maybe it's one of its dependencies that's missing. Try http://www.dependencywalker.com/ to identify which one.

After that...?